# Coroutine doesn't work in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I need to make a screenshot in Unity. I did it the next way:

```
public void Capture(){
    StartCoroutine(CaptureScreenshot());
}

private IEnumerator CaptureScreenshot(){
    GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
    canvas.SetActive(false); // hide all buttons
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MMMM_hh_mm_ss_tt");
    Application.CaptureScreenshot("screenshot" + timestamp + ".png");
    Debug.Log("Screenshot was captured.");
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    canvas.SetActive(true); // restore all buttons
    yield return null;
}
```

When I invoke `Capture()`, canvas hides but neither screenshot takes nor text logs.

What is wrong with this code? Thanks for response.

Comment: is the coroutine running on a game object that lives on the canvas?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes

Comment: Disabling the Canvas makes every child inactive aswell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your script is running on a object in the canvas when you do `canvas.SetActive(false);` that also disables the script, preventing the coroutine from continuing from `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();`.

Move the script to a game object that does not live on the canvas and it should solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this.

```
foreach(Transform t in GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform)
{
 if(transform.gameObject.name != t.gameObject.name)
 t.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Be sure to re-enable them with

```
foreach(Transform t in GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform)
    {

     t.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
```

Comment: You should explain that what the code does is instead of disabling the canvas it disables all game objects on the canvas except the object that the script lives on. (note, if the script lives inside a nested object this wont fix the problem because you are still disabling a parent of the script)

Comment: That was already explained by Max Play in the comments, that being said, i offered an alternative if OP did not want to move the script. @ScottChamberlain